# Slide down and slide up div - HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css

This what I am trying to do has to be with pure CSS and HTML. I also can't use `-webkit-transition: top 1s; and also all divs height has to be set to auto depends on content so can't use fixed height for divs and also can't touch max-height values.

The problem is when i try to hide parent div then all children appears for a second before it slides up. How to fix it? Just try it with snippet below.

```css
#variation {
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 0.05em solid #ddd;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
height: auto;
max-height: 0px;
transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;

}
#variation .variation_div_main {
visibility: visible;
transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-moz-flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
}
.variation_div {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-moz-flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#t1:checked ~ #div-main #variation,
#t1:checked ~ #div-main #fiat {
visibility: visible;
display: block !important;
max-height: 2000px;
}
#t1:checked ~ #div-main .variation_div_main:not(#fiat)  {
display: none !important;
}

#t2:checked ~ #div-main #variation,
#t2:checked ~ #div-main #ford {
visibility: visible;
max-height: 2000px;
}
#t2:checked ~ #div-main .variation_div_main:not(#ford)  {
display: none !important;
}
```

```html
close <input type="radio" id="t0" name="tabs" checked="checked"/><br>
fiat <input type="radio" id="t1" name="tabs"/><br>
ford <input type="radio" id="t2" name="tabs"/><br>

<div id="div-main">
<div id="variation">
<div id="fiat" class="variation_div_main">
<div class="variation_div">
<div class="variation_div_photo">
Picture 
</div>
<div class="variation_div_description">
<b>Fiat Ducato</b><br>
Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description 
</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="ford" class="variation_div_main">
<div class="variation_div">
<div class="variation_div_photo">
Picture
</div>
<div class="variation_div_description">
<b>Ford Transit</b><br>
Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description 
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. just need to put `max-height: 0px;
transition: 2s ease-in-out;` in `#variation .variation_div_main` section. Hope that may be helpfull for someone

```css
#variation {
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 0.05em solid #ddd;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
height: auto;
max-height: 0px;
transition: 2s ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;

}
#variation .variation_div_main {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-moz-flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
max-height: 0px;
transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
.variation_div {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-moz-flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#t1:checked ~ #div-main #variation,
#t1:checked ~ #div-main #fiat {
max-height: 2000px;
}
#t1:checked ~ #div-main .variation_div_main:not(#fiat)  {
display: none !important;
}

#t2:checked ~ #div-main #variation,
#t2:checked ~ #div-main #ford {
max-height: 2000px;
}
#t2:checked ~ #div-main .variation_div_main:not(#ford)  {
display: none !important;
}
```

```html
close <input type="radio" id="t0" name="tabs" checked="checked"/><br>
fiat <input type="radio" id="t1" name="tabs"/><br>
ford <input type="radio" id="t2" name="tabs"/><br>

<div id="div-main">
<div id="variation">
<div id="fiat" class="variation_div_main">
<div class="variation_div">
<div class="variation_div_photo">
Picture 
</div>
<div class="variation_div_description">
<b>Fiat Ducato</b><br>
Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description 
</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="ford" class="variation_div_main">
<div class="variation_div">
<div class="variation_div_photo">
Picture
</div>
<div class="variation_div_description">
<b>Ford Transit</b><br>
Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description 
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved your problem very easily here is what I add to your CSS, 
If you just add

```
#t0:checked ~ #div-main #variation{
 display: none !important;
}
```

This is a new change it will slowly slide up whenever you click on close

```
#t0:checked ~ #div-main #variation .variation_div_main{
    visibility: collapse;
    transition: 0.8s visibility;
}
```

into your style sheet, it will work just fine, I will put both CSS and HTML down below

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>StackOverFlow</title>
    <style>
        #variation {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 0.05em solid #ddd;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: auto;
            max-height: 0px;
            transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
            overflow: hidden;

        }
        #variation .variation_div_main {
            visibility: visible;
            transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -moz-flex-direction: column;
            position: relative;
        }
        .variation_div {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            -webkit-flex-direction: row;
            -moz-flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #t1:checked ~ #div-main #variation,
        #t1:checked ~ #div-main #fiat {
            visibility: visible;
            display: block !important;
            max-height: 2000px;
        }
        #t1:checked ~ #div-main .variation_div_main:not(#fiat)  {
            display: none !important;
        }

        #t2:checked ~ #div-main #variation,
        #t2:checked ~ #div-main #ford {
            visibility: visible;
            max-height: 2000px;
        }
        #t2:checked ~ #div-main .variation_div_main:not(#ford)  {
            display: none !important;
        }

        #t0:checked ~ #div-main #variation{
            display: none !important;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

close <input type="radio" id="t0" name="tabs" checked="checked"/><br>
fiat <input type="radio" id="t1" name="tabs"/><br>
ford <input type="radio" id="t2" name="tabs"/><br>

<div id="div-main">
    <div id="variation">

        <div id="fiat" class="variation_div_main">
            <div class="variation_div">
                <div class="variation_div_photo">
                    Picture
                </div>
                <div class="variation_div_description">
                    <b>Fiat Ducato</b><br>
                    Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description Some fiat description
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="ford" class="variation_div_main">
            <div class="variation_div">
                <div class="variation_div_photo">
                    Picture
                </div>
                <div class="variation_div_description">
                    <b>Ford Transit</b><br>
                    Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description Some ford description
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you like it, and please let me know if your problem doesn't solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but it just doesn't slide up. I tried that before. I also answered my own question as I found a solution. Have a look below; Thank you anyway.

Comment: Okay Marcin I have changed the way to hide when you click on close,

        #t0:checked ~ #div-main #variation .variation_div_main{
            visibility: collapse;
            transition: 0.8s visibility;
        }

This should work fine, let me know if that is not what you want.